# how do I associate a HTTPConduit in Spring XML

Tags: cxf

i need to set below client userProxy=true in environment.properties

http:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive" ConnectionTimeout="300000" ReceiveTimeout="900000"   ProxyServer="${proxyHost}" ProxyServerPort="${proxyPort}"/>

else

http:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive" ConnectionTimeout="300000" ReceiveTimeout="900000"/>

How can i possible in xml.

```
    <http:tlsClientParameters secureSocketProtocol="${ssl.secure.socket.protocol:TLSv1.2}" disableCNCheck="${ssl.common.name.check.disable:false}">
        <sec:trustManagers>
            <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="changeit" resource="mytrusts.keystore" />
        </sec:trustManagers>
        <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="changeit">
            <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="changeit" resource="test.keystore" />
        </sec:keyManagers>
    </http:tlsClientParameters>

    <http:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive" ConnectionTimeout="300000" ReceiveTimeout="900000"   ProxyServer="${proxyHost}" ProxyServerPort="${proxyPort}"/>
</http:conduit>
```

Comment: Its very urgent

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options. You can associate your conduit with your service by specifying the correct name attribute within your conduit element. The structure is *QName*.http-conduit.

For instance:

```
<http:conduit name="{http://example.com/}HelloWorldServicePort.http-conduit">
    [...]
</http:conduit>
```

You can also bind it to any service by replacing the QName with a star.

```
<http:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    [...]
</http:conduit>
```

Or use the endpoint address:

```
<http:conduit name="https://www.example.com/myservice">
    [...]
</http:conduit>
```

For details, see: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-Theconduitelement